# Syntax of wolfram alpha solution entry (using #1 and &)

Tags: equation-solving

I try to understand the solution that solves the following equation

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=argmin+%28f%28x%29%3D%28x%2F%28a-x%29%29%5E2*b%2Ba-x%29+for+a%3E%3Dx%3E%3D0

It is written that the solution is x == Root[-a^3 + (3 a^2 + 2 a b) #1 - 3 a #1^2 + #1^3 & , 1]

What is the #1 symbol means? and is there a numerical solution for the equation?

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! The `#1` is the first argument slot for a function, and the syntax `f[#1] &` represents a function. For example, `#1 + 5 &` is the function that adds 5 to its input. The first argument of `Root` is the function that we're taking a root of. See the documentation for [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) for examples. Also check out [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/63584).